# Why the result from PHP chr(238) is different with javascript String.fromCharCode(238) and how to fix that?

Tags: javascript, php

So the old program was in PHP and I would like to rewrite in node.js (javascript).

Why the result from PHP chr(238) is different with javascript String.fromCharCode(238) and how to fix that?

PHP:
chr(238) = `�`

Javascript:
String.fromCharCode(238) = `î`

The result from above is used as header for TCP connection.

Comment: JS uses Unicode, while PHPa chr() cannot... only 1-byte encodings

Comment: what do you mean different? can you provide an example

Comment: @LarsStegelitz do you have any idea how to fix that?
@Ghost from PHP: chr(238) = `�` from javascript: String.fromCharCode(238) = `î`

Comment: The docs explain it fully http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone how do I get the same value of `chr(238)` in node.js?

Answer (score 2):

Use mbstring [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-chr.php) lib to process unicode in PHP. Something like this:

```
mb_chr(238);
```

Or in PHP 5:

```
<?php
function exchr($u) {
    return mb_convert_encoding('&#' . intval($u) . ';', 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
}
echo exchr(238);
```